# How to pass file path from asp.net matlab ne builder dll tool to Matlab function

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Am Newbie to Matlab. Am trying to build online image compression tool using matlab and asp.net. I have written image compression algorithm using matlab and it is working fine and I have deployed it using ".NET Assembly". Then it generates *.dll files. I have included those files in ASP.NET Project -> References -> *.dll. In ASP.NET I have provided option to browse to upload the image. I am saving that image in one folder. I have created an object for dll and calling compression function by passing saved image path.  But am getting error like I need to pass MWArray.

code for compression.m:

```
function compression(img)
imread(img)
compression logic goes here
end
```

dll file name is compression_tool and class is CompressionTool

code for online.aspx.cs

```
path="images/sample.jpg"
compression_tool.CompressionTool obj = new compression_tool.CompressionTool();
obj.compression(path);
```

Am not getting how to do. Please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what exactly is the error message? also try to use full path to the input image `C:\path\to\sample.jpg` not just relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke a method from the assembly generated by Builder NE, you can pass most native .NET type directly which will map to the equivalent MATLAB type.

If for some reason this not working for you, you can explicitly create an instance of one of the derived `MWArray` classes that wrap internal MATLAB types.

For example:

```
string name = "Amro";
obj.greet(name);
```

Assuming `obj.greet` is the interface for a compiled MATLAB function that receives a string. Otherwise you can explicitly write:

```
obj.greet(new MWCharArray(name));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is solved. I was not using native .NET builder.